# map dictionary values to lists in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with a column as such:

```
column
--------
['getNode', 'getCodec', 'PackStore', 'DownRoute']
['MessageDigest', 'getInstance', 'SecureRandom']
...
```

I also have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
getNode: 1,
getCodec: 2, 
PackStore: 3, 
DownRoute: 4,
MessageDigest: 5, 
getInstance: 6, 
SecureRandom: 7,
...
}
```

My goal is to replace each item in the lists within column with the values that appear in the dictionary. i.e.:

```
column
--------
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7]
...
```

I have tried calling:

```
df.column.map(dict)
```

But i get an error: `unhashable type: 'list'`

Any additional help would be awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `apply`:

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).map(dct).tolist())
```

Or just:

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: list(map(dct.get, x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
df.explode('column').squeeze().map(dd).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 2, 3, 4]
1       [5, 6, 7]
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Option 2:

```
pd.Series([list(map(dd.get, l)) for l in df['column']])
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 2, 3, 4]
1       [5, 6, 7]
dtype: object
```

## Timings:

#### apply-lambda-map-tolist:

```
%timeit df.column.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).map(dd).tolist())
```

> 1.15 ms ± 39.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#### explode-squeeze-map-groupby:

```
%timeit df.explode('column').squeeze().map(dd).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

> 2.56 ms ± 78.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#### pd.Series constructor with list comprehension and map:

```
%timeit pd.Series([list(map(dd.get, l)) for l in df['column']])
```

> 88.7 µs ± 4.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#### column explode-map

```
%timeit df.column.explode().map(dd).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

> 1.21 ms ± 28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#### column-apply-lambda-list-map

```
%timeit df.column.apply(lambda x: list(map(dd.get, x)))
```

> 152 µs ± 4.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops
> each)

Comment: Would you like test explode solution as well ?

Comment: Could you please put my new one to test?

Comment: @BENY Done.... See results

Comment: @U12-Forward Done... See Results...

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `explode`

```
df.column.explode().map(dd).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```